# Problems with magento payment methods

Tags: php, magento, payment, payfort

Good afternoon.

I have a problem with my payment method.

I followed this guide http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/.

On backend everything is good.

But on frontend new method doesnt appear.

Here some code Creativator_Payfort.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creativator_Payfort>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Creativator_Payfort>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creativator_Payfort>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Creativator_Payfort>
    </modules>

    <default>
        <payment>
            <payfort>
                <model>payfort/standard</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>CUSTOM CARD</title>
                <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
                <submit_url>https://someurl.com</submit_url>
                <merchant_id>Insert merchant id</merchant_id>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>15</sort_order>
            </payfort>
        </payment>
    </default>

    <global>
        <models>
            <creativator_payfort>
                <class>Creativator_Payfort_Model</class>
            </creativator_payfort>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <creativator_payfort>
                <class>Creativator_Payfort_Helper</class>
            </creativator_payfort>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <creativator_payfort>
                <class>Creativator_Payfort_Block</class>
            </creativator_payfort>
        </blocks>

    </global>




    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <Creativator_Payfort>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Creativator_Payfort</module>
                    <frontName>payfort</frontName>
                </args>
            </Creativator_Payfort>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <creativator_payfort>
                    <file>creativator/payfort.xml</file>
                </creativator_payfort>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

The system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <payfort translate="label comment" module="payment">
                    <label>Payfort</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New Order Status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status</source_model>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                        <submit_url>
                            <label>Gateway URL</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>58</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </submit_url>
                        <merchant_id>
                            <label>Merchant ID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>59</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </merchant_id>
                        <allowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Payment Applicable From</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </allowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Countries Payment Applicable From</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <depends><allowspecific>1</allowspecific></depends>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        </sort_order><sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </fields>
                </payfort>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

And finally model Standard.php:

```
<?php

class Creativator_Payfort_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

    protected $_code = 'payfort';

    protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = true;

/**
* Return Order place redirect url
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
    {
    //when you click on place order you will be redirected on this url, if you don't want this action remove this method
        return Mage::getUrl('payfort');
    }

}
```

P.S. I have read similar posts about similar problem, but it didn't help. I have surely missed something important.

So I will be very thankfull for your help

Comment: you have to add and call the block in the payment template.

class Creativator_Payfort_Block extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods
{

     //do your stuff here

}

Comment: Thanks, user3040610, but I dont get how this will help me to show my method on the checkout page in section payment methods?

Comment: I am not sure but there may have been conflict in extending Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract class. Debug to check whether getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() function is returning value or not.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have defined your model inside "creativator_payfort" tag so you need to use "creativator_payfort/standard" for model.

2) active tag is missing

```
        <payfort>
            <model>creativator_payfort/standard</model>
            <active>1</active>`
```